# Cannot get value from HashMap by position

Tags: android, listview, hashmap

I have an hashmap and I need to recover the value at a certain position using a int var.

```
Map<String,String> uniList = new HashMap<String, String>();
// ESSE3 CINECA
uniList.put("UniMe","Università degli studi di Messina");
uniList.put("UniBa","Università degli studi di Bari");
uniList.put("UniCz","Università degli studi di Catanzaro");
uniList.put("UniBas","Università degli studi di Basilicata");
uniList.put("UniPrt","Università degli studi di Napoli Partenophe");
uniList.put("UniBs","Università degli studi di Brescia");
uniList.put("UniCam","Università degli studi di Camerino");
uniList.put("UniPr","Università degli studi di Parma");
uniList.put("UniUd","Università degli studi di Udine");
uniList.put("UniRoma3","Università degli studi Roma3");
uniList.put("UniLuspio","Università degli studi internazionali(Roma)");
uniList.put("UniSt","Università per stranieri Dante Alighieri");
uniList.put("UniIuo","Università degli studi di Napoli, l'Orientale");
uniList.put("UniSs","Università degli studi di Sassari");
uniList.put("UniIusm","Università degli studi Roma4");
uniList.put("UniEr","Università Europea di Roma");
uniList.put("UniMol","Università degli studi di Molise");
uniList.put("UniSg","Università delle scienze gastronomiche del Piemonte");
uniList.put("poliBa","Politecnico di Bari");
//ESSE3 INDIPENDENTE
```

list.getPosition is not working and makes the application to crash:

```
Map<String, String> list = Globals.getUniList();
Toast.makeText(getContext(), list.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Please use list.get("key") to get the value from Map.